# Memory leak in Python Program - Memory in task manager very high, memory printouts are normal

Tags: python, memory-leaks

I've noticed that when I open task manager and monitor my programs memory usage, it increases linearly to over 5GB in 30 minutes. I expect usage to increase over time but this is insane.

I'm not going to post my code because its very long and spans 10 different py files.

If I had to guess where the problem is, I would assume it has to do with Pytesseract OCR or Selenium. I take screenshots once per second and thats the only thing I can think of that could use that much ram. But the variables holding the images should go out of scope at the end of the function call. I think it might also be selenium if it is storing the chrome instance in the Python program.

I used a library called "muppy" to print out the memory usage of different types and the results did not match what was in the task manager.

this is the code I'm using to print out my memory usage.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ...
    # this code runs every 30 seconds
    all_objects = muppy.get_objects()
    sum = summary.summarize(all_objects)
    summary.print_(sum)
```

When task manager showed 5gb of ram usage, muppy showed:

```
                                types |   # objects |   total size
===================================== | =========== | ============
                         <class 'list |      357807 |    157.64 MB
                         <class 'dict |      291873 |     54.72 MB
                          <class 'str |      469144 |     33.66 MB
  <class 'bs4.element.NavigableString |      109679 |     11.52 MB
              <class 'bs4.element.Tag |       95831 |      5.12 MB
                         <class 'type |        2410 |      2.45 MB
                         <class 'code |       15267 |      2.15 MB
                          <class 'int |       41775 |      1.13 MB
                        <class 'tuple |        9362 |    611.35 KB
                          <class 'set |         693 |    528.59 KB
          <class 'bs4.element.Comment |        3588 |    421.11 KB
                      <class 'weakref |        3262 |    254.84 KB
                    <class 'frozenset |         920 |    252.50 KB
            <class 'collections.deque |         304 |    187.62 KB
                   <class 're.Pattern |         350 |    174.91 KB
```

Did I call this memory logger from the wrong spot maybe?

What is the best way to debug these things? I didn't even know you could get memory leaks in python.

Comment: Debugging memory leaks in a large codebase you don't understand is hard, I'd try reducing (does the leak still happen if you disable certain bits of processing - selenium, OCR, reduce the screenshots size?) Do numbers in muppy's output increase with time? I'd look at bs4 object first, since you can guess where they come from. Where are they allocated? What happens if you disable that part?

Comment: That's a very good idea - I'm going to try and disable parts to try and locate the source of the problem. 

Muppy's output does increase with time - but its expected. It's logging stuff into a list for about an hour before it's cleared. 100mb sounds fair I guess. It does't account for the rest of the 4.9 GB's though. 

I'll LYK if I find what part of the code is causing the issue.

Comment: Well, disable the parts that you know are leaking first! You can then try to guess what's leaking the object reported by muppy. (BTW, you can make two snapshots and inpect the diff - both the summary data and the individual objects - to make guesses as to which code is leaking.)